# Gravitational pull of a sphere with hole

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, vectors

> A sphere with uniform density $\rho$ has a spherical hole in it as shown. It has radius $R$ and the total mass of the sphere(which includes the hole) is $M$. We seek to find the magnitude of the gravitational field at point $P$.
> [image]

My initial thought was to account for the pull of the sphere *with* the hole, then subtract off the hole's gravity. Using this method, I would have the total gravity $g$ be equivalent to $$\frac{G(M+M_{hole})}{R^2}-\frac{G\cdot M_{hole}}{d^2}$$
where $d$ is the distance between the center of the hole and $P$.

To calculate the mass of the hole, we can simply first find the density $\rho$ by using the given mass $M$ and then dividing by the volume of the sphere *with* the hole. Then we can calculate the mass of the hole and solve.

However, I immediately realized an issue. This method only accounts for the magnitude of gravitational pull, and not the direction. If the hole was in the center of the sphere, then this would not matter, but in this case, the hole is not in the center, so my method would not work.

I know I should treat this as two equations, one for the $x$ component and one for the $y$ component, and there would obviously be some trigonometry, but I can't see the general way to set this equation system up. Does anyone know how to solve this?

It would be useful to bring in some numbers I suppose. Let $R=53,000$ km and $M=4\cdot 10^26$ kg. What would be the magnitude of the gravitational field on $P$?

Comment: Hint : vectors.

Comment: well yea thats what i was thinking lol

Answer (score 2):

Your method for solving the magnitude of the forces looks OK.
Once you have solved that, just make a drawing of the directions of the two forces. The Pythagorean theorem might be useful....